# ERROR: You can't use a prefix with `\begingroup'

Tags: babel, multicol, expl3, report

Here is a minimal example of a document which does not compile.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\newtheorem{test0}{test0}
\newtheorem{test1}{test1}
\newtheorem{test2}{test2}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The error message (as seen on emacs) states:

> ERROR: You can't use a prefix with `\begingroup'.
>
> --- TeX said ---  
>                      \begingroup  l.20 \begin{document}
>
> --- HELP --- From the .log file...
>
> I'll pretend you didn't say \long or \outer or \global or \protected.

I tried adding `etex` to the list of package, but I can not see any difference

And I must confess I don't have any clue of why it is a minimal example. 
I can't imagine how this exact set of package interract so that, any of them removed solve the problem. 
Furthermore, I find surprising that changing `report` to `article`, or `[francais]` to `[english]` also solve the problem.

Alas, I prefer not to do any of those change if I can, because all of those package are useful in my thesis, which is certainly not small enough to be an `article`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This example compiles for me without problem. Do you have an outdated TeX distribution?

Comment: Here is my guess: `l.20` refers to `\begin{document}`, which is where [`minitoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) starts reading its `.mt0`, `.mt1`, ... files. If you have some of those hanging around, and they're out-of-date, it may cause an unexpected error. Clear those from your current folder (in addition to other auxiliary files) and you should be able to compile without problem... well, as something within the `document` environment. So this has nothing to do with all the other packages interacting with one another... showing the `.log` file would also help isolate the problem.

Comment: With updated TeX Live 2015 this works for me without errors. When you use the option "-file-line-error" with pdflatex, you should at least get information about which file the "line 20" is in. (Or maybe you can already get it from the .log-file?)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
last ubuntu version. I'm right now trying to update.

Comment: @ArthurRainbow: Well, TL 2013 is 'old'

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce this with TL 2013.

Comment: @Werner: And the folder are cleared, there is not a single document apart the .tex

Comment: It's some bad interaction between `expl3` and `newtxtext`; it seems to be solved if you load `expl3` *after* `newtxtext`. Also move `hyperref` as the last loaded package.

Comment: Thank you @egreg, it seems to work perfectly now. Even if, to be honest, this seems nonsens to me. It just works.

Answer (score 1):

As egreg commented, it seems it suffices to have hypperref as last package, and expl3 avfter newtxtext. It now compiles. Even if I couldn't say why.

Comment: It happens because of the way `etex` was set up to switch from the standard to the extended pool in conjunction with mistaken use of `\begingroup` before register assignment.